# My wife was given limited stay stamp in USA and came back in time

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

My wife has a visitor visa for the US (10 year validity) which she got 2 years ago. She gave birth to our son in the US and came back along with the baby. A month ago she went again to the US to visit her grandparents but after a long interrogation, the immigration officer at the border gave her a limited stay stamp for one month and told her to pay the hospital bill (from her previous stay/childbirth) which was already waived by the hospital. She contacted the hospital and they refused any payment as the bills had already been paid by a charity.

Now my wife has returned to India before the one month time limit set by the immigration officer. Will she face any problems if she goes back in the future?

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. I have edited your question for clarity. There are a few details which you should tell us - Did she apply for a fresh visa and was given a 1 month visa or did she try to use her previous visa but at the border was asked to leave in one month. The hospital bills were her's from her previous visit or someone else's?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why would USCIS care about unpaid hospital bills, which do not even exist in the first place? How did they even know?

Comment: When they saw my son’s passport they ask you gave birth in usa and my wife said yes and than asked who paid hospital bill and than wife said hospital waive off my bill and than they said you have to pay so i am also confused about that because  why they are concerned about bill it is not that right to even ask hospital about that

Comment: So the bill was actually fully paid by charity so they stuck on like why would you don’t paid bill you can’t have baby for free but that was useless comment what should we do know is there any problem than